# How do I connect with my Verizon Mobile Broadband dongle?

Tags: 10.10, internet, modem-manager

When I try and set up my mobile connection through the connection wizard it doesn't work at all. There is no indication that my computer even recognizes it. Any pointers? This is a Verizon dongle.

Comment: It might help if you found out the device id of your dongle. You can get it with `lsusb` (look at the results). It looks something like this: `046d:c30e`. Search for that id on the internet and you'll surely find guides on how to set the stick up. Report your id back here, if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to install the `usb-modeswitch` package, if your Verizon device is a "flip-flop" device.

A "flip-flop" device is one that initially appears as a CD-ROM device that contains Windows drivers for the device. This driver, when installed, sends a special command to the device to let it know that it can "flip" into modem mode.

Usually these devices have no Linux drivers on them. The `usb-modeswitch` program sends the special command unconditionally, and lets Linux's built-in facilities talk to the modem.

Comment: What do you mean "flip-flop?"

Comment: usb-modeswitch is already installed.

Comment: Oh dear. Hmm. Well, I updated my answer to answer your question, anyway. You may need a newer version of `usb-modeswitch` (if one exists---unlikely given you're using 10.10) that knows about your device.

Comment: This dongle does seem to have these features, it just doesn't show up at all in Ubuntu.